# SQL - Trying to get a user's position within a database, by column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, discord.py

So i have some code I'm running with SqlLite3:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM (SELECT userid, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Level DESC) AS Level FROM users) a WHERE userid = 267410788996743168;")
```

This here returns none, why? What im trying to do is (on command) get an users position in the database based on a certain column. (e.g. `Youre ranked 120 out of 5382 users.` ) Is there an easier way to achieve this, or should i fix the param?

Comment: First question: Are you certain that this user actually exists?

Comment: Is this your actual code?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - yes, that (discord) userid is mine, and its in the db.
forpas yes, should i put more in for context?

Comment: Post the table's create statement.

Comment: @forpas https://pastebin.com/C0ya7diH

Comment: @Parfait this is not problem in SQLite. The numeric value implicitly is converted to a string: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f0f423e9a3fb4e53a0fee84b51f0fa4e

Comment: How do you know `cur.execute` is `None`? Did you attempt to iterate on its results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that user actually exists, then the only way that you don't get any results would be that the actual value that you have in the table contains spaces, because you have defined the column as `TEXT`.
Try by casting the value to an integer:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT userid, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Level DESC) AS Level FROM fishyusers) a 
WHERE userid + 0 = 267410788996743168;
```

or by trimming the value and comparing to a string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT userid, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Level DESC) AS Level FROM fishyusers) a 
WHERE TRIM(userid) = '267410788996743168';
```

If this succeeds then you should update the table to remove leading or trailing spaces from the column `userid`:

```
UPDATE fishyusers
SET userid = TRIM(userid);
```

Comment: I dont think the table contains spaces, because things like `c.execute(f'SELECT * FROM fishyusers WHERE userid = {authorid}')` works just fine. I tried the 2 things you recommended, plus a `fetchone()` and i printed it. Both printed `[]` :(

Comment: @averwhy can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 ?

Comment: I got this, which is a bit different from mine... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3cde21d415059e8b396543083e31e19b Im going to try deleting the entire DB and starting again. (theres no important data)

Comment: If you use TRIM() you must definitely supply the parameter as a string (in quotes). Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=efd5bad2218bd9a218e1075b5d94d08f